# How can I get my T60 to write a cd/dvd faster than 2xs?

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad, compact-disc, dvd-burning

XP SP3 IBM T60.

I have been informed that the  dvd ram in my computer will write faster than 2xs only on one specific manufacturers media. All other media is restricted to 2xs. How can I change this?

Thanks

Comment: Some media make that restriction. If you look up specs on media for sale, you will notice that they also have a speed on them, this is the max speed that a burner can write to them. Check the specs on the media for its speed. If this is not the issue comment back.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean "only on one specific *medium*"? If so, it's probably the disk itself which has the speed limitation (so you shouldn't attempt to exceed it, disks limit their burn/read speed for a reason).

Comment: Sounds like a comment on the question regurgitated. I like how you worded it though. +1 due to a friendly way of wording it and being correct even if you regurgitated my comment...

Comment: It can't be regurgitation if I said it before you ;) I feel it's pretty obvious that this is the issue at hand, the question is more just to show why I'm not answering the question directly.

Comment: I have been informed that unless I use a particular make of cd/dvd, my computer will not burn at more than 2xs, the the computer will vary the speed according to the medium's maker. I cannot find the source again. Is this wrong?

Comment: That's not incorrect -- the medium itself can assert the r/w speed.

Comment: Well, I'm using 2 different types of 8x DVDs. Both write at 2x.?

Comment: It's possible that your drive only overlaps on support with the medium at 2x.